# Are there books written specifically for bilingual or polyglots (i.e. not for learning the language but for proficient speakers)?

Tags: learning-methods

I started an experiment a while back of writing a story with someone who speaks a different native language to me (but we are both able to speak English). I thought the idea of stories where if you can read in one language then you will understand one part, and if you read another language then you will understand the other part, but if you can read in both languages then another story emerges to be rather interesting.

I am wondering if anyone is aware of reading materials or resources that is written in more than one language not as a translated version, but something that is intended for someone who is proficient at more than one language. That way they can practice more than one language at the same time rather than one language at a time.

Comment: I wish I could answer this because when I was really young (7 or 8 maybe), I found a 'choose your own adventure' book in my school library that would go English-French-English-French as you went through the story (at least I assume it was French, I can't remember). I really wish I could give more information than that but I don't remember anything! Good luck!